# Why SMS Manager wont send message?

Tags: java, android

My newest problem is that when I tried to make One-Time Sms message sent from my app, it wont send... And the most weird thing is that there appears actually zero errors???

My code:

```
try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phonenum , null , String.valueOf(num), null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message failed, please try again.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> permission in Manifest file??

Comment: I mmean added i have added it...

Comment: try to the add the source address in sendTextMessage()(supply second argument instead of null)

Comment: Do you use a real device or an emulator? If real - do you have nough balance in your account? Are you able to send sms manually?

Comment: But if i use emulator for just testing... what about then? I dont have android phone...

Comment: If you are using emulator, you have to configure telnet server. Try in a real device. Another question, on your debug test, the variable 'num' is not null or empty or zero?

Comment: Num is generated as Random but i didnt add it to this code, so what is telnet server?